# ClickOnce app: Version and settings lost after app restart

Tags: wpf, clickonce

I have a C#/WPF app that uses ClickOnce for deployment. There is a scenario where the app needs to restart (the user changes a database). I do it by:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(System.Windows.Application.ResourceAssembly.Location);
System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
```

After restart, it seems that the app has  issues:

1. The version becomes 1.0.0.0.
2. The current database setting is set to default (it is in the application's Properties.Settings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know that I fully understand the question, but I do know there is an issue with the method you are using to restart the application if it is a ClickOnce application. When you restart the application this way, `ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed` will be `false`. See this post for a full explanation: http://bit.ly/RKoVBz.

I haven't verified the proper way to restart the application yet, but I'll update this a soon as I do.

Comment: The way suggested in the end is indeed the way to restart a WPF-ClickOnce app. Sadly, it means you have to reference `WinForms.dll`.

Comment: Thanks for verifying that for me. I won't be in the office to double check it for myself until tomorrow. It is indeed a sad fact that you must reference `WinForms`. That really leaves a bad taste in my mouth.